# Xero Contact Credit Limits in API

Tags: xero-api

Xero has finally released a "Credit Limit" facility for Customer accounts.

We are using the https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts endpoint to receive Customer balances.

But, there is no sign yet of the "Credit Limit" being added to this.

If it is going to be added to this endpoint, when will it be available. If it is already in another endpoint, then please can anyone point me to the right one?

Comment: I searched the PHP API repository for "limit" and it doesn't look like it's available anywhere. I have voted on your uservoice thing.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2/search?q=limit

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get attention on something like this is to raise a user voice: https://xero.uservoice.com/